# Are these Equivalence Relations?

Tags: equivalence-relations

I am having some trouble determining if these are equivalence relations. Specifically, I am not sure if I am supposed to check for reflexiveness, symmetry and transitivity in the ordered pairs of the relation or every possible ordered pair in the set.

(a) R = {(1, 1),(1, 2),(2, 1),(2, 2),(3, 3)} on set {1, 2, 3}

(b) R = {(1, 1),(1, 2),(2, 1),(2, 2),(3, 3)} on set {1, 2, 3, 4}

(c) R = {(1, 2),(2, 3),(1, 3)} on set {1, 2, 3}

Comment: I think if you looked at the definitions of reflexivity, symmetry, and transitivity you would realise which ones are equivalence relations. Which ones do you *think* are?

Comment: Please ask only one question per post.

Comment: " if I am supposed to check for reflexiveness, symmetry and transitivity in the ordered pairs of the relation or every possible ordered pair in the set"  What would be the point of every possible pair?  The question is about the *relation*, not the set.  If you consider every *possible* pair then $(x,x)$ and $(x,y),(y,x)$ and $(a,b),(b,c),(a,c)$ will *always* be possible.  But what do any of those have to do with the *relation*?

Comment: @amWhy I think it would be really silly if someone asked three separate questions for the content of this one...

Comment: @Nika  If the OP showed effort on all three, or specified what they don't understand about the questions, I'd be okay.  But this site is not a site for users looking for homework completion.  Ideally, they should asking one question well, and then using their knowledge to answer extremely similar others on their own.  This is not a "post your homework" site.

Comment: So it seems to me that none of these are equivalence relations then? A is not symmetric because the relation is missing (2,3), (3,2), (1,3), and (3,1). B is not reflexive because it is missing (4,4). C is not reflexive because it is missing (1,1) (2,2), and (3,3)

Comment: The first relation is an equivalence relation.  Symmetry requires only that **if $(x, y) \in R$** then $(y, x) \in R$.  If there is a pair $(x, y) \notin R$, then $(y, x)$ needn't be in $R$.

Comment: " I think it would be really silly if someone asked three separate questions for the content of this one... "  It'd pointless to ask three questions either separately or as a single post when there is only *one* issue they need explained.

Comment: "A is not symmetric because the relation is missing (2,3), (3,2), (1,3), and (3,1)"  But it doesn't need those to be symmetric.  If it has $(2,3)$ then it *must* have $(3,2)$ and if it has $(3,2)$ it *must* have $(2,3)$.  But it doesn't have to have either of them.

Comment: For ever single pair $(a,b)$ has it also has $(b,a)$.  It has $(1,1)$ and id also has $(1,1)$.  It has $(1,2)$ and it also has $(2,1)$.  It has $(2,2)$ and it also has $(2,2)$ and it has $(3,3)$ and $(3,3)$.  So it is symmetric.  It is true is does not have $(3,1)$ but that's okay because it does not have $(1,3)$ so it doesn't need $(3,1)$....

Comment: @fleablood If OP simply posted "I am not sure if I am supposed to check for reflexiveness, symmetry and transitivity in the ordered pairs of the relation or every possible ordered pair in the set" the question might have been closed for lacking details or clarity. I see the problems (a),(b) and (c) as extra context. Also, OP has been a member for a week, so I don't think their attempt at providing more context for their problem is "pointless". Even if it was, the advice to the OP would then be that the extra context is unnecessary, *not* that this post has too many questions to be addressed.

Comment: @amWhy "or specified what they don't understand about the questions".  To be fair the OP said "Specifically, I am not sure if I am supposed to check for reflexiveness, symmetry and transitivity in the ordered pairs of the relation or every possible ordered pair in the set" *is* specifying what s/he didn't understand.  Admittedly, I was perplexed as to how on earth one could think of all possible pairs, but his/her comment about symmetry when $(1,3)$ and $(3,1)$ weren't included made that clear.

Answer (score -1):

To be reflexive $R$ must have all *possible*  $(a,a)$ pairs.  1) does.  2) and 3) do not.

Symmetry.  $R$ does not need all *possible* $(a,b);(b,a)$ pairs.  But for every $(a,b)$ pair that it *does* have, it must have the symmetric $(b,a)$ pair.  1) has the pair $(1,2)$ so it needs $(2,1)$ to be symmetric.  It does so that is fine.  (And vice versa; it has $(2,1)$ so it needs $(1,2)$ which it does).

on the other hand as 1) does *not* have $(1,3)$ so it *doesn't* need $(3,1)$.  (And if 1) had $(3,1)$ it would need $(1,3)$; but it doesn't have $(3,1)$ so it does not need $(1,3)$.

Of all the $(a,b)$ (where $a \ne b$) pairs that 1) has; that is $(1,2)$ and $(2,1)$ it must have those in reverse.  And it does.  So it is symmetric.

It's worth noting that if a relation $R$ didn't have *any* $(a,b)$ pairs it would be symmetric as it would *need* any $(b,a)$ pairs.

As for transitive:  That means for any $(a,b)$ an $(b,c)$ that it *does* have it must also have $(a,b)$.

1) has $(1,2)$ and it has $(2,1)$ so it must have $(1,1)$.  It does.  And it has $(2,1)$ and it has $(1,2)$ is it must have $(2,2)$.  It does.

In theory we need to check andy $(a,b)$ and $(b,b)$ so see if it has $(a,b)$ but .... that's trivial.  It it has $(a,b)$ it has $(a,b)$ so we cshouldn't have to check those.

Now the only $(a,b),(b,c)$ pairs that 1) has are $(1,2),(2,1)$ and $(2,1),(1,2)$.  So we checked those all and transitivity holds.   We don't need ot check any pairs it *doesn't* have (such as $(1,2),(2,3)$ to see if it has $(1,3)$) as those are irrelevant.

ANyway.  1) has reflexivity because it has all $(a,b)$ for every $a$ in the set. 2) fails as it does not have $(,4,4)$.  3) fails entirely.

1) and 2)have symmetry as for all $(a,b);a\ne b$ that they have theeny have $(b,a)$.  3) fails as it has $(1,2)$ but not $(2,1)$ etc.

All three have transitivity.  So 1) is the only equivalence relation.

....

==== old answer =====

If you check every *possible* order pair in the set, than that wouldn't tell you anything about the pairs in *relation*.  So what would be the point?

Also as $(x,x)$ is always a possible pair the the set of *possible* pairs will always be reflexive and as $(x,y)$ and $(y,x)$ will always be possible the set of all *possible* pairs will be symmetric and similarly transitive.

But we should we care about what could *possibly* happen when you are concerned only with what *does* happen in $R$?

1) is reflexive because they have all possible $(a,a)$ pairs namely $(1,1)$ and $(2,2)$ and $(3,3)$ but 2) and 3)  is not because 2) doesn't have $(4,4)$ and 3) has none of $(1,1),(2,2)$ or $(3,3)$. *doesn't* have any of them.  (And what do where care that they are *possible* if they are not actually *in* $R$?)

====added later====

In reading you comments I see you are confused about symmetry.  And now I understand why you asked about *possible* pairs which didn't make any sense to me at first but now I can understand your confusion.

To be symmetric then for every pair $(a,b)$ that the set *does* have then the set must *also* have $(b,a)$.  But it doesn't need to have *either* $(a,b)$ or $(b,a)$ in the first place.

To be symmetric it must have both, *OR* it could have neither.

1) as $(1,2)$ so to be symmetric it must have $(2,1)$.  ANd it does.  But since it doesn't have $(1,3)$ it doesn't have to have (in fact it *can't* have) $(3,1)$.

For the pairs it *does* have $(\color{red} 1,\color{blue}1), (\color{red}2,\color{blue}1), (\color{red} 1,\color{blue}2), (\color{red}2,\color{blue}2),(\color{red}3, \color{blue}3)$ to be symmetric it must contain the symmetric pairs:  $(\color{blue}1, \color{red} 1), (\color{blue}1,\color{red}2), (\color{blue}2,\color{red} 1), (\color{blue}2,\color{red}2),(\color{blue}3,\color{red}3)$... which it does.

Notice that any $(a,a)$ is always symmetric to itself so we don't actually have to check them.  The only ones we need to check are $(a,b)$ where $a\ne b$.

In the case of 1)  we have $(1,2)$ so we need $(2,1)$ and we have it.  And we have $(2,1)$ and so we need $(1,2)$ and we have it.

Comment: I'm not *answering* the question.  I am addressing the op's concern and questions.  The ope didn't express any concern about transitivity.  The op was concerned about whether to consider *possible* pairs.

Comment: But you did just answer the question!!  An hour after your initial comments.

Comment: I thought you said you weren't going to follow this.  Go away.

Comment: I followed to watch your multiple attempts to comment on the answer, and only after I deleted my answer(s) in comments, did you bother to fully answer.  Not often does one get multiple attempts to answer a question, particularly when every point you made in your second and third major edit was already made in comments.  Glad to have motivate you to improve your "answer", even if I had to answer first.